# How to fix c++ not outputting the input

Tags: c++

How to fix c++ not outputting the input I got no idea! So please help me I am new to c++!

```cpp
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{

    std::cout << "Please type if you want pickup or delivery: ";

    string input;
    string pickup;
    string delivery;
    string address;

    if (input == "pickup")
    {
        cout << "What pizza do you want(press r for a random pizza and c for cheese pizza!): ";
        cin >> input;
    }

    if (input == "delivery")
    {
        cout << "Tell me your adress and i will deliver a random pizza to ur house: ";
        getline(cin,address);
        cin.ignore();
    }

    if (address == address)
    {
        cout << "Thx we will delivery the pizza to " << address << " tommorow at 3PM!" << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `std::cin.ignore()` **before** `std::getline()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not asking for input...

```
std::cout << "Please type if you want pickup or delivery: ";
```

after this line you need to get the user to input either pickup or delivery

ie

```
std::cin>>input;
```

next you need to swap `getline(cin,address);` and `cin.ignore();`arround.. currently you are asking for input and then clearing the buffer.

also `if (address == address)`
what are you trying to achieve here?

your code can be written like this

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{

    std::cout << "Please type if you want pickup or delivery: ";

    string input;
    string pickup;
    string delivery;
    string address;
     cin>>input;
    if (input == "pickup")
    {
        cout << "What pizza do you want(press r for a random pizza and c for cheese pizza!): ";
        cin >> input;
    }

    if (input == "delivery")
    {
        cout << "Tell me your adress and i will deliver a random pizza to ur house: ";
         cin.ignore();
        getline(cin,address);
        cout << "Thx we will delivery the pizza to " << address << " tommorow at 3PM!" << endl;
    }

 
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I was trying to say if I enter the address it will print the words and the address the person inputed(But thx u fixed my proplem)

Comment: my code does that?
because you had cin.ignore the address was not printing, but from the beginning you were not entering pickup or delivery